Snakemake (v8.10.7) fails to locate conda (or micromamba)
I am trying to build a workflow in snakemake, but as soon as I use conda, snakemake immediately reports an error. I wrote a simple example to illustrate this error.
Here is a snakefile file:
rule a_conda_rule:
    shell:
        "which htop"

Everything seems fine after execution:
$ snakemake -j1
Assuming unrestricted shared filesystem usage.
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job             count
------------  -------
a_conda_rule        1
total               1

Select jobs to execute...
Execute 1 jobs...

[Fri Apr 12 23:59:21 2024]
localrule a_conda_rule:
    jobid: 0
    reason: Rules with neither input nor output files are always executed.
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

$HOME/local/htop/bin/htop
[Fri Apr 12 23:59:21 2024]
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2024-04-12T235921.291193.snakemake.log
(snakemake)

But once you add a line of conda:
rule a_conda_rule:
    conda: "environment.yml"
    shell:
        "which htop"

It immediately becomes like this:
$ snakemake -j1 --use-conda
Assuming unrestricted shared filesystem usage.
Building DAG of jobs...
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/cli.py", line 2068, in args_to_api
    dag_api.execute_workflow(

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/api.py", line 589, in execute_workflow
    workflow.execute(

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 1122, in execute
    self.dag.create_conda_envs()

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 420, in create_conda_envs
    env.create(self.workflow.dryrun)

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 393, in create
    pin_file = self.pin_file
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake_interface_common/utils.py", line 33, in __get__
    value = self.method(instance)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 103, in pin_file
    f".{self.conda.platform}.pin.txt"
        ^^^^^^^^^^

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake_interface_common/utils.py", line 33, in __get__
    value = self.method(instance)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 96, in conda
    return Conda(
           ^^^^^^

  File "$HOME/micromamba/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 659, in __init__
    self.prefix_path = self.info["conda_prefix"]
                       ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

KeyError: 'conda_prefix'

I guess this might be a problem with environment variables, because my .bashrc file has been slightly set up.
The content of my .bashrc file is:
export PATH=~/local/htop/bin:$PATH
export PATH="$HOME/local/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

# >>> mamba initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'mamba init' !!
export MAMBA_EXE='$HOME/bin/micromamba';
export MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX='$HOME/micromamba';
__mamba_setup="$("$MAMBA_EXE" shell hook --shell bash --root-prefix "$MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX" 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__mamba_setup"
else
    alias micromamba="$MAMBA_EXE"  # Fallback on help from mamba activate
fi
unset __mamba_setup
# <<< mamba initialize <<<

source ~/.biostar.sh

The content of .biostar.sh is:
#
# A minimal BASH profile.
#
# Sets up the environment for the Biostar Handbook.
#
# This file is sourced by the .bashrc file.
#
# Don't edit this file directly, it may be rewritten by the install script.
#

# ls uses different flags for colors on Mac and Linux
if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]; then
  alias ls='ls -hG'
else
  alias ls='ls -h --color=auto'
fi

# Safe versions of the default commands.
# Ask permissions before overwriting files.
alias rm='rm -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias cp='cp -i'

# Extend the program search PATH and add the ~/bin and ~/edirect folders.
export PATH=~/bin:~/edirect:$PATH

# Makes the prompt more user friendly: colors, hostname, path, etc.
export PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '

# Necessary for the command line sort to work correctly.
export LC_ALL=C

# This is used on macOS to turn off zsh warning.
export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1

# Alias conda and mamba to micromamba
alias mamba=micromamba
alias conda=micromamba

Maybe it’s because snakemake can’t recognize micromamba?
This is my first time asking a question here, any of your suggestions are very helpful to me, thank you very much.

Looks like you've aliased mamba/conda to micromamba. I'm not sure of the specific differences, but I don't think they are fully interchangeable, at least definitely not in the eyes of Snakemake, hence the issue. You can install mamba with micromamba though: micromamba install -c conda-forge mamba

Indeed, after reconstructing the recommended mamba setup from Snakemake’s installation guide, everything is functioning smoothly. It appears that Snakemake is unable to locate micromamba. Thank you for your patience!
